# Setting background color of PyQt5 QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

I spent some time struggling to use `.setStyleSheet` to change the background color of a QWidget used as a window, using Python 3.5.2, PyQt 5.9 and Qt 5.9.1. I tried various suggestions I found online, but what ended up working was changing the object name of the QWidget, referring afterwards to that name as an ID in the stylesheet.

My question is, is this behaviour I can rely on, or is there an alternative way of doing it?

Working code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QApplication)

class BgColorExperiment(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        QLabel('some words 一些單詞', self).move(20, 0)

        self.setObjectName('MainWidget')
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #MainWidget {
                background-color: #333;
            }
            .QLabel {
                color: #fff;
            }
        """)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('QWidget Bg Color Experiment')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    EXP = BgColorExperiment()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

Comment: What exactly did you try that **didn't** work? I tried your example and it works fine without setting the object name, and using `QWidget` or `*` as the selector.

Comment: @ekhumoro Those two other selectors you mention work too! What didn't work was trying to use `.QWidget` (with a dot) as the selector, or changing the QPalette that the QWidget uses while calling `setAutoFillBackground(True)`, or setting the `WA_StyledBackground` attribute of the QWidget to `True`. I couldn't get any of these three things to work.