# PyQT5 : Qlabel overlay eachother even after using grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm new and I just want to learn how to code some UI. My problem with PyQt5 is the following.

I just create 3 labels (each named label, label1 and label2). One is supposed to contain just text, another one is supposed to print the time and the third one is supposed to print the position (x, y) of the mouse.

When I use the grid layout, it just print Qlabels at the same place even if I specify a different position with grid add widget.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My code :

```
#Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007891/setting-background-color-of-pyqt5-qwidget
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QToolTip, QPushButton, 
                             QMessageBox, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTime

class BgColorExperiment(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # moves the widget to a position on the screen at x=300, y=300 coordinates
        self.left = 300
        self.top  = 300
        # resizes the widget (250px wide and 150px high) 
        self.width  = 450
        self.height = 450
        # title of Widget shown in the titlebar
        self.title ='Suivi des BDs crées'
        # sets the application icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('suivibdicon.png'))
        # Set the status bar
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Engineered by idiots')
        # parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Artiste
        self.setObjectName('MainWidget')
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #MainWidget {
                background-color: #333;
                }
            .QLabel{
                color: green;
                background-color: #333;
                selection-color: yellow;
                selection-background-color: blue;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
            .QToolTip {
                background-color: #333;
                color: #fff;
                border: red solid 1px;
                opacity: 100;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
            .QMessageBox {
                background-color: #333;
                }
            QStatusBar {
                color: green;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
        """)
        # violence
        self.label  = QLabel('position of the mouse', self)
        self.label1 = QLabel('some words 一些单词', self)
        self.label2 = QLabel('digital clock', self)

        grid = QGridLayout()

        # just blablabla
        grid.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)

        # Digital Clock
        grid.addWidget(self.label2, 1, 0)

        # Mouse tracking
        x, y = 0, 0
        self.text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self) # display the x and y coordinates of a mouse pointer in a label widget.
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

#        # push button widget and set a tooltip (useless)
#        #btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
#        #btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget for refresh')
#        #btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
#        #hbox.addWidget(btn)

        # set the grid
        self.setLayout(grid)
        # set the window size using the setGeometry
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.show()                                 # displays the widget on the screen

    def closeEvent(self, event): # Define behavior when clicking on the x button on the title bar
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',  "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e): # for following the position of the mouse
        x, y = e.x(), e.y()
        text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.label.setText(text)

    def showTime(self): # for printing the time (format = 'hh:mm:ss')
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.label2.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    EXP = BgColorExperiment()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_()) # mainloop of the application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

void `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget *widget)`

Sets the given widget to be the main window's central widget.

Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QToolTip, QPushButton, 
                             QMessageBox, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTime

class BgColorExperiment(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # moves the widget to a position on the screen at x=300, y=300 coordinates
        self.left = 300
        self.top  = 300
        # resizes the widget (250px wide and 150px high) 
        self.width  = 450
        self.height = 450
        # title of Widget shown in the titlebar
        self.title ='Suivi des BDs crées'
        # sets the application icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('suivibdicon.png'))
        # Set the status bar
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Engineered by idiots')
        # parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Artiste
        self.setObjectName('MainWidget')
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #MainWidget {
                background-color: #333;
                }
            .QLabel{
                color: green;
                background-color: #333;
                selection-color: yellow;
                selection-background-color: blue;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
            .QToolTip {
                background-color: #333;
                color: #fff;
                border: red solid 1px;
                opacity: 100;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
            .QMessageBox {
                background-color: #333;
                }
            QStatusBar {
                color: green;
                font-family : Consolas;
                font-size: 10pt;
                }
        """)
        # violence
        self.label  = QLabel('position of the mouse', self)
        self.label1 = QLabel('some words 一些单词', self)
        self.label2 = QLabel('digital clock', self)

        centralWidget = QWidget()                         # +++++
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)              # +++++

        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)                 # +++++ centralWidget

        # just blablabla
        grid.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)

        # Digital Clock
        grid.addWidget(self.label2, 1, 0)

        # Mouse tracking
        x, y = 0, 0
        self.text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self) # display the x and y coordinates of a mouse pointer in a label widget.
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

#        # push button widget and set a tooltip (useless)
#        #btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
#        #btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget for refresh')
#        #btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
#        #hbox.addWidget(btn)

        # set the grid
#        self.setLayout(grid)                                          # -----
        # set the window size using the setGeometry
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.show()                                 # displays the widget on the screen

    def closeEvent(self, event): # Define behavior when clicking on the x button on the title bar
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',  "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e): # for following the position of the mouse
        x, y = e.x(), e.y()
        text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.label.setText(text)

    def showTime(self): # for printing the time (format = 'hh:mm:ss')
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.label2.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    EXP = BgColorExperiment()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_()) # mainloop of the application
```

[image]